# Sympy matrix exponential raises ValueError

Tags: python, matrix, sympy

I have a 3x3 symbolic matrix and I want to calculate the matrix exponential of it using Sympy.

```
from sympy import *

a0,a1,y0,y1,k,t = symbols('a0 a1 y0 y1 k t')

A = Matrix([[-y1*t-a1*t,-y0*t,0],[t,-a1*t,-k*t],[0,t,-a1*t]])

res = exp(A)
print(res)
```

This gives the following error:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 13
    import fnmatch, glob, traceback, errno, sys, atexit, locale, imp, stat
DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/core/cache.py", line 94, in wrapper
    retval = cfunc(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'MutableDenseMatrix'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/core/cache.py", line 94, in wrapper
    retval = cfunc(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'MutableDenseMatrix'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/core/compatibility.py", line 419, in as_int
    raise TypeError
TypeError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/idlelib/run.py", line 559, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "/home/kaguro/Documents/PROJECT/Paper-simulation/Finite-time/Model B/extra.py", line 7, in <module>
    res = exp(At)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/core/cache.py", line 96, in wrapper
    retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/core/function.py", line 473, in __new__
    result = super(Function, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/core/cache.py", line 96, in wrapper
    retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/core/function.py", line 288, in __new__
    evaluated = cls.eval(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/functions/elementary/exponential.py", line 320, in eval
    return arg.exp()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/matrices/matrices.py", line 3208, in exp
    P, J = self.jordan_form()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/matrices/matrices.py", line 1811, in jordan_form
    jordan_basis = [eig_mat(eig, 1).nullspace()[0] for eig in blocks]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/matrices/matrices.py", line 1811, in <listcomp>
    jordan_basis = [eig_mat(eig, 1).nullspace()[0] for eig in blocks]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/matrices/matrices.py", line 1011, in nullspace
    reduced, pivots = self.rref(iszerofunc=iszerofunc, simplify=simplify)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/matrices/matrices.py", line 941, in rref
    ret, pivot_cols = self._eval_rref(iszerofunc=iszerofunc,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/matrices/matrices.py", line 593, in _eval_rref
    reduced, pivot_cols, swaps = self._row_reduce(iszerofunc, simpfunc,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/matrices/matrices.py", line 713, in _row_reduce
    assumed_nonzero, newly_determined = _find_reasonable_pivot(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/matrices/matrices.py", line 5327, in _find_reasonable_pivot
    if x.equals(S.Zero):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/core/expr.py", line 757, in equals
    constant = diff.is_constant(simplify=False, failing_number=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/core/expr.py", line 683, in is_constant
    if b is not None and b is not S.NaN and b.equals(a) is False:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/core/expr.py", line 834, in equals
    mp = minimal_polynomial(diff)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/polys/numberfields.py", line 655, in minimal_polynomial
    result = _minpoly_compose(ex, x, domain)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/polys/numberfields.py", line 534, in _minpoly_compose
    res = _minpoly_add(x, dom, *ex.args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/polys/numberfields.py", line 362, in _minpoly_add
    mp = _minpoly_op_algebraic_element(Add, a[0], a[1], x, dom)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/polys/numberfields.py", line 242, in _minpoly_op_algebraic_element
    mp1 = _minpoly_compose(ex1, x, dom)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/polys/numberfields.py", line 547, in _minpoly_compose
    mp1 = minimal_polynomial(ex1, x)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/polys/numberfields.py", line 655, in minimal_polynomial
    result = _minpoly_compose(ex, x, domain)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/polys/numberfields.py", line 557, in _minpoly_compose
    res = _minpoly_mul(x, dom, *ex.args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/polys/numberfields.py", line 374, in _minpoly_mul
    mp = _minpoly_op_algebraic_element(Mul, a[0], a[1], x, dom)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/polys/numberfields.py", line 244, in _minpoly_op_algebraic_element
    mp2 = _minpoly_compose(ex2, y, dom)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/polys/numberfields.py", line 559, in _minpoly_compose
    res = _minpoly_pow(ex.base, ex.exp, x, dom)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/polys/numberfields.py", line 337, in _minpoly_pow
    mp = _minpoly_compose(ex, x, dom)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/polys/numberfields.py", line 534, in _minpoly_compose
    res = _minpoly_add(x, dom, *ex.args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/polys/numberfields.py", line 362, in _minpoly_add
    mp = _minpoly_op_algebraic_element(Add, a[0], a[1], x, dom)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/polys/numberfields.py", line 279, in _minpoly_op_algebraic_element
    res = _choose_factor(factors, x, op(ex1, ex2), dom)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/polys/numberfields.py", line 70, in _choose_factor
    if abs(f.as_expr().evalf(prec1, points)) < eps:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/core/expr.py", line 171, in __abs__
    return Abs(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/core/cache.py", line 94, in wrapper
    retval = cfunc(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/core/function.py", line 473, in __new__
    result = super(Function, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/core/cache.py", line 94, in wrapper
    retval = cfunc(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/core/function.py", line 288, in __new__
    evaluated = cls.eval(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/functions/elementary/complexes.py", line 473, in eval
    arg = signsimp(arg, evaluate=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/simplify/simplify.py", line 383, in signsimp
    e = sub_post(sub_pre(expr))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/simplify/cse_opts.py", line 16, in sub_pre
    adds = [a for a in e.atoms(Add) if a.could_extract_minus_sign()]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/simplify/cse_opts.py", line 16, in <listcomp>
    adds = [a for a in e.atoms(Add) if a.could_extract_minus_sign()]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/core/expr.py", line 2386, in could_extract_minus_sign
    (negative_self).extract_multiplicatively(-1) is not None)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/core/expr.py", line 2208, in extract_multiplicatively
    newarg = arg.extract_multiplicatively(c)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/core/expr.py", line 2221, in extract_multiplicatively
    newarg = arg.extract_multiplicatively(c)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/core/expr.py", line 2134, in extract_multiplicatively
    elif c == self:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/core/numbers.py", line 2248, in __eq__
    return Rational.__eq__(self, other)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/core/numbers.py", line 1906, in __eq__
    integer_log(self.p//m, 2) == (t, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/core/power.py", line 147, in integer_log
    y = as_int(y)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/core/compatibility.py", line 425, in as_int
    raise ValueError('%s is not an integer' % (n,))
ValueError: 1 is not an integer
```

I don't understand why is it not working. Earlier I had used a 2x2 matrix with similar kind of form, and it worked perfectly (albeit very complicated looking).

The eigenvalues can be found of this matrix, but asking for eigenvectors gives the same error. So I can't use the diagonalisation method manually either (didn't expect this to work, because then Sympy would have done that).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are probably using an older version of SymPy. With current SymPy this is just extremely slow (I'm not sure how long it takes).

Comment: The function here can compute this matrix exponential: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/21585

Comment: Thank you very much! This method of using ILT is fantastic and works for me.